# Vagrant : why can I not access nginx with domain name?

Tags: vagrant

I am using `Vagrant` on Windows 10.

I have installed centos 7 vagrant box,it is running correctly.

`Vagrantfile` is like this：

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "dev"
  config.vm.hostname = "vagrant-dev"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.3"
  config.vm.synced_folder "d:/vagrant_env/www/", "/var/www"

end
```

I installed nginx in centos 7 vagrant box, and I can access nginx welcome page with ip `192.168.33.3`.

I want to access it with domain name,so I configure `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
 file in windows:

```
192.168.33.3   www.example.vagrant   //add this line into hosts file of windows
```

and configure `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file in centos 7:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.vagrant;
    //...
}
```

I try accessing `www.example.vagrant` on windows host,but it does not work.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There's two better solutions to this:

- Use [xip.io](http://xip.io) for your address. In this case `http://example.192.168.31.3.xip.io/` will route to your address.
- Set up a DNS entry for that which can be resolved. An inexpensive `.com` or `.info` test domain at a registrar which makes updating easy (e.g. Amazon Route 53) is always handy for this.

Some programs stubbornly refuse to read entries in `/etc/hosts` or the equivalent in Windows.

Comment: how to install it?

Comment: You don't install it. That's a service anyone can use. It just works. Click the link there to the [xip.io](http://xip.io) site.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `192.168.31.3:8080` in your browser. If you can see your server, then just make your redirect like that: `192.168.31.3:8080   www.example.vagrant`

`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080`

At this point you are saying "whatever happens inside Vagrant on port 80, forward it to port 8080 on host machine". You have to communicate with your Vagrant machine on port 8080.

Also your IP is wrong `192.168.33.3` vs `192.168.31.3`

Comment: I update the IP, I use `192.168.33.3`. I can not see the server with `192.168.33.3:8080` ,but can see it with `192.168.33.3`